# Different colorbar in same plot

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, matlab-figure, color-mapping

A simple question. I have a figure. I need to hold it, and put some dots on it using scatter plot. Figure has a `colormap(jet)`. I want these new dots to be black. I tried using caxis.

This is what I did:

```
cmap=colormap(jet);cmap=[[0;0;0]';cmap;[1;1;1]'];caxis([-pi pi]);colormap(cmap);
```

I set the values of new dots to 10 or -10. So they are black or white. But the lowest values or highest values in my original image is also black or white. Since the `caxis` works as less that or equal to basis.

If you can suggest some other method, thats also fine.

Thanks in advance.

N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two approaches.

1. if you do the scatterplot with line or plot you can specify the color: `line(x_data,y_data,'Color','k')` (k is black).
2. you can draw the scatter plot in a second axis which you overlay. Following command should do most of the work (but maybe you should adjust):

---

```
a1 = gca;

a2 = axis('Color','none'... % to make it transparent
,'Position',get(a1,'Positon')... % to have it at exactly the same position
,'XLim',get(a1,'XLim')... % same xrange
,'YLim',get(a1,'YLim')... % same yrange
,'XTick',[],'YTick',[]) % turn of ticks as they are already in the other axis
```

Comment: Well it worked. If I only wanted to show one color in scatter, 'color' works. But i want negative values to be white and positives to be black. I will test the other solution soon. So far i am happy with one color.